# CSS Drop Down Menu + FLAT UI

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, fadein, transition

http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/

I wanted to create a Css drop down menu, I have the drop down portion done, however I can't seem to emulate the transitions and have no idea how to code those. Here is what I have so far, thanks in advance for your help.

```
body {
 font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 20px 50px 150px;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
background: #E3CAA1;
```

}

```
ul {
text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
    ul li {
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
    ul li:hover {
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
  }
    ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: The transitions happen by transitioning opacity from 0 to 1. But if you're using Flat UI, doesn't it already come with built-in dropdowns? You shouldn't have to write this much custom code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 20px 50px 150px;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
background: #E3CAA1;}
ul {
text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
    ul li {
    font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
    ul li:hover {
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
  }
    ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li>Dropdown menu items</li>
<li>Dropdown menu items</li>
<li>Dropdown menu items
<ul>
<li>Drop - Dropdown menu items</li>
<li>Drop - Dropdown menu items</li>
<li>Drop - Dropdown menu items</li>
<li>Drop - Dropdown menu items</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Dropdown menu items</li>
<li>Dropdown menu items</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would probably be more helpful to explain what you changed and why. A link to a working example would also be useful. 90 lines of uncommented code doesn't make for a very clear answer.